# Is it possible to create an IPv6 subnet when my router have /64 prefix?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ipv6

My ISP gives me a Zhone Router with an IPv6 address using **`/64`** prefix. The wireless of the Zhone router sucks badly, so I bought a new router with IPv6 capabilities to amplify the range of wireless in my apartment. It was a Tp-Link Archer C60. It has the IPv6 Bridge option, so there was no problem distributing IPv6 over the Wireless... but this router is gone, the WAN port is damaged.

When using the Tp-link in bridge mode all clients got the IPv6 using the Zhone router WAN prefix (a valid and open IPv6 acessible from anywhere on the Internet, starting with `2001:1284`).

So I bought a new router with IPv6... but this router does not have IPv6 Bridge option. However, it have options to configure DHCPv6.

I'm new to IPv6 and need to know if there is an option to create subnets if my router already is using prefix /64. I tried to set DHCPv6 from /65 to /127 subnets in the new router but it says that these are invalid prefixes.

In automatic IPV6 mode, it appears that the router is trying to create a subnet with addresses starting from fe80::. It already can get the right local IPv6 from the Zhone router `fe80::4002:71ff:fe43:bafd`, but can't ping it.

So, can anyone point me directions in how to configure a IPv6 subnet?

The Zhone router is using stateless DHCPv6 with router advertisement enabled.

Comment: `fe80` it is non routable link-local and works only inside your local LAN without assistane from any router. While many providers says they gives you /64, in fact they giving either /56 /48 or some even /128 (You need to find online exact case).

Comment: Make sure you have enabled prefix delegation on the Zhone router. If it has no such option, yell at your ISP until they give you a modem which isn't complete rubbish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I bought a new router with IPv6 capabilities to amplify the range of wireless in my apartment.

Technically you don't need a *router* to amplify the Wi-Fi range. You need a Wi-Fi access point (aka "wireless range extender"); it just so happens that home routers include one.

If you *do* have a router, then "IPv6 bridge" is still not the feature you want. You should use regular basic bridging (which handles all L2 protocols) – it's present in more routers and doesn't involve nearly as much behind-the-scenes magic as protocol-specific bridging. (It doesn't even require the "router" to support IPv6 at all!)

Most home routers already have such a basic bridge between Wi-Fi and the "LAN" ports, anyway. So just search this site for tutorials on how to convert a router into an access point.

---

Back to IPv6...

> In automatic IPV6 mode, it appears that the router is trying to create a subnet with addresses starting from fe80::

No. That's a link-local address that *all* IPv6-capable devices set up, without any involvement of a router. They'll have a link-local address *even if* global addresses are also present.

> Is it possible to create an IPv6 subnet when my router have /64 prefix?

Technically any prefix length is valid. However, only /64's are supported with stateless address autoconfiguration, i.e. SLAAC.

(This requirement originally existed because SLAAC used the device's EUI-64 (MAC) address. With the adoption of RFC 7217 it is now mostly artificial, but so far only OpenBSD supports non-/64 prefixes.)

You could have a subnet without SLAAC, but then you would need to assign addresses either manually (which is a pain) or via DHCPv6 (which many OSes do not support – e.g. Android).

So *practically* each subnet **still needs to be a /64.**

However, check whether your ISP supports giving you a larger prefix (e.g. a /60 or even /56) via DHCPv6 Prefix Delegation. If they do, then your router can use this to obtain as many /64's as it needs, without bridging.

Comment: Well, in fact I bought a new Router with wireless because here where I live is hard to find a good AP-only device (and when I found, is too pricey). BTW I already knew it but I thank you for your clarification. I'm also able to setup the router as an access point disabling the new router DHCP (v4 and v6) and pluging the WAN port in any of LAN ports. I just tought it was easier to setup DHCPv6.